# Changing a php variable depending on radio button

Tags: php

I have a form with 2 radio buttons - depending what the user selects, I want to change a variable to change the sorting order from date to title:

```
<form action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get" id="searchform2">
        <input type="radio" name="sort" value="date" checked> Order by date
        <input type="radio" name="sort" value="title"> Order by title
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit2" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php if(isset($_GET['sort']) == "date") {
    $sort = ($_GET['sort']);
    $order = "DESC";
} else {
    $sort = ($_GET['sort']);    
    $order = "ASC";
} 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'policies',
    'orderby' => $sort,
    'order' => $order
);  
?>
```

At the moment the sort variable is outputting the correct stuff depending on the the selection but the order isn't. It outputs "DESC" not matter what is selected. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your if condition makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if-condition seems to be broken, try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] === "date") {
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];
    $order = "DESC";
} else {
    $sort = $_GET['sort'];    
    $order = "ASC";
} 
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'policies',
    'orderby' => $sort,
    'order' => $order
);  
?>
```

But this is dangerous as you are using unfiltered input from the user. If you just use `$sort` for a DB query for example, you would introduce SQL-Injection if you don't sanitize it first!

Answer (score 0):

`isset($_GET['sort'])` can never be equals to `date` but true or false. Do this instead:

```
<?php 
$sort = ($_GET['sort']);
if( !empty($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == "date") {    
    $order = "DESC";
} else {  
    $order = "ASC";
}
```

EDIT: I'm not sure of what's your doing with that, but your code seems vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<form action="" method="post" id="searchform2">
        <input type="radio" name="sort" value="date"> Order by date
        <input type="radio" name="sort" value="title"> Order by title
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit2" class="search-submit" value="Search" name="chkdata" />
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['chkdata'])){
if($_POST['sort'] == "date"){
    $_POST['sort'] = "DESC";
} else {
    $_POST['sort'] = "ASC";
}
}

echo $_POST['sort'];
```